# How to print index number on tableview cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, indexing

I want to print the number of the tableview cell based on the number of tableview cells that are there so if there are 15 cells. The first cell should be 1 and the 15th should state 15. I want this printed before a fetch that is already being printed. I posted a picture of what I am looking for below.

```
 cell.textLabel?.text = [" Course: ",attr1," : ", attr2].flatMap { $0 }.reduce("", +)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
let text = [" Course: ",attr1," : ", attr2].flatMap { $0 }.reduce("", +)
cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row+1) \(text)"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works I just want the first cell to start at 1 and not 0 is that possible?

Comment: @sillymilly: yes just add +1. I updated the code. Hope this helps.